# Search string in nested array of objects and return matched objects as result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I have the array of objects as `input` shown below. This has property `vertical` as type string, `platformList` is an array and `radar_metadata` is nested object

I want to search for a string and get those object which has string value in it. Its like a search functionality that i am trying to implement.

```
let input = [
 {
    "vertical": "Partner",
    "platformList": [
      "Access"
    ],
    "radar_metadata": {
      "state": "Verify",
    }
  },
 {
    "vertical": "Integration",
    "platformList": [
      "Identity"
    ],
    "radar_metadata": {
      "state": "Closed",
    }
  }
]
```

So i implemented this function to loop through the object elements and get those object whose string matches or is included in the object.

```
const filterByValue = (array, string) => {
    return array.filter((o) =>
      Object.keys(o).some((k) =>
        o[k].toString().toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  };
```

When i get this result1, i search for `Partner` text in the array of object and i get the result as follows.

```
let result1 = filterByValue(input, 'Partner')
----Output----
result1 = [
 {
    "vertical": "Partner",
    "platformList": [
      "Access"
    ],
    "radar_metadata": {
      "state": "Verify",
    }
  }
]
```

Now the complexity increases when i want to search for `Ident` text or `Clos` text. Because these searches are to be performed in nested object (radar_metadata) as well as array (platformList)

```
let result2 = filterByValue(input, 'Ident')
let result3 = filterByValue(input, 'Clos')
----Output----
result2 = [
 {
    "vertical": "Integration",
    "platformList": [
      "Identity"
    ],
    "radar_metadata": {
      "state": "Closed",
    }
  }
]

result3 = [
 {
    "vertical": "Integration",
    "platformList": [
      "Identity"
    ],
    "radar_metadata": {
      "state": "Closed",
    }
  }
]
```

Can someone let me know how to modify my `filterByValue` function to include these scenarios too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by destrcturing your object:

```
    const filterByValue = (array, string) => {
        return array.filter((obj)=>{
        // destructure your obj to extract the data
        const {vertical, platformList, radar_metadata: {state}} = obj;
        // make an array from the destructured data
        const data = platformList.concat(state,vertical);
        // return if string is included
        return data.some( (el)=>el.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase()) );
        });
    };
```

Here is a link for more info on destructuring:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
const filterByValue = (array, string) => {
  return array.filter((o) =>
    Object.keys(o).some((k) => {
      const value = o[k];
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        return filterByValue([value], string).length > 0;
      } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return filterByValue(value, string).length > 0;
      } else {
        return value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());
      }
    })
  );
};
```